# Can I print something with console.log() in Promise? (DEBUGGING)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, mobx

I'm trying to understand someone else's code and here is the original code

```
// Using Mobx over Redux here. I don't think it's relevant to this problem. 
@action.bound init() { 
    this.time_interval = setInterval(actions.initTime, 1000);

// other file    
export const initTime = () => ({
    server_time: window.time || moment.utc(),
});
```

And I'm trying to console.log but it gives me an error.

```
@action.bound init() {
    // I guess it's checking if the current time is same with server's time.
    this.time_interval = setInterval(actions.initTime, 1000);
    console.log(actions.initTime); <- gives me function. 
    console.log(actions.initTime.server_time); <- undefined

// other file    
export const initTime = () => ({ <- This is returning Promise.? I usually used Redux-Thunk to handle all actions and I almost forgot how Promise worked. 
    console.log(window.time); <- syntax error
    server_time: window.time || moment.utc(),
});
```

**So how do we print `window.time` and `moment.utc()`?** Thanks!

**UPDATE**

```
export const initTime = () => ({
    server_time: window.time || moment.utc(),
}).then(console.log()); 
^- console.log(window.time) prints undefined
^- console.log(moment.utc()) prints undefined
^- console.log( window_time || moment.utc()) prints a function with few parameters such as 'is_UTC', 'isValid', '_locale'.
```

Data:

Comment: [`moment.utc()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) returns a moment object, use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to get a string in your preferred format or other methods listed in the [Display](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) section of the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like its returning a promise there
I think this is what you are looking for

```
export const initTime = () => {
    console.log(moment.utc())
    return {
      server_time: window.time || moment.utc()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
export const initTime = () => ({ <- This is returning Promise.? I usually used Redux-Thunk to handle all actions and I almost forgot how Promise worked. 
    console.log(window.time); <- syntax error
    server_time: window.time || moment.utc(),
});
```

It happens because you're using implicit return here, and it returns an object. You can't use console.log inside an object.